# Make the width of the figure (including 2 minipages) same as the paper

Tags: floats, minipage

I have 2 minipages side by side as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      left part
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      right part
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}}
  \captionof{figure}{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
```

Now the width of the whole `figure` is a little bit shorter than the width of the paper. I would like to make them **exactly** the same.

Could anyone tell me which parameter I could change to realize that?

Comment: change `0.48` to `0.5`?

Comment: That will exceed the width of the paper...

Comment: Always add a `%` after the trailing `{` of `\fbox` to avoid a space being inserted here by the end-of-line character. This will give you some extra whitespace at the left of the border.

Comment: Also, no need to use `\captionof{figure}` inside `figure`. Just use `\caption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\framebox`   instead of `\fbox`.

```
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \framebox[1\linewidth][t]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}%
      left part is going to be very big sentence that goes into two lines
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}%
      right part is going to be very big sentence that goes into two lines
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  \captionof{figure}{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As per Martin's comments on using `\framebox` and verbatim text/catcode changing material, this code will work as desired using `\fbox`

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      left part right part is going to be very big sentence that goes into two lines
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      right part right part is going to be very big sentence that goes into two lines
    \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}}
  \captionof{figure}{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
```

However, you have to use

```
\usepackage{calc} % as per Stephan's advice.
```

for this to work properly.

PS. If you want this to go up to the paper width (do you really want to do that?), you have to reduce the margins to zero using geometry.

I am of the opinion that you can simply use `\caption` inside `figure` environment (instead of `\captionof` which will be used outside `\figure` environment)

[image]

Comment: Always add a `%` after the trailing `{` to avoid a space being inserted here by the end-of-line character. You can see on your example image that there is an extra space on the left because of this.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks for noting. A typo which occured due to some laziness. I have corrected it. Thanks

Comment: I think it should be `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax` instead of `1\linewidth` to compensate for the space added by the frame. Otherwise the content of the framebox will be exactly be `\linewidth`, not the framebox itself.,

Comment: @MartinScharrer Does it look like that? Pl. see the new image.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the space after `\fbox{`:

```
\fbox{%
```

Secondly, replace `0.48\linewidth` by

```
0.5\linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule
```

which means deducing the amount of space added horizontally by `\fbox`.

You need to load the `calc` package if you're not already doing that.

As Harish Kumar noticed, `\linewidth` is 'counted locally' inside `minipage`, so don't apply this twice if you don't want to (why are you nesting minipages anyway?)

Your example again, with changes and some unneccessary stuff removed:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}%
      left part
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}%
      right part
    \end{minipage}}
  \captionof{figure}{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers tell you how to force the frame width. But in case the frame was just for debugging, or just out of interest as it's not mentioned in the other answers; the reason why the edges of your two `minipages` were not forced out to the page edges was that the `\hfill` between them has no effect and is the same as `\hspace{0pt}`  `\fbox` (like `\mbox` or `\hbox`) sets its content to *natural width* and `\hfill` glue, although stretchy has natural width 0pt. By using `\framebox` (or just removing the `\fbox`) TeX is trying to set the line to a specified width and so the stretch implied by `\hfill` is allowed to push the `minipages` apart.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `minipage`s exactly `0.5\textwidth`, and you want to frame it, I would recommend the `mdframed` package, otherwise you have to do manual adjustments for the `\fbox` command as demonstrated in the other answers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{mdframed}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
      left part
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}% <--- NOTE!!
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
      right part
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{mdframed}
  \caption{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force a frame with a given content width using `\framebox{<width>}{<content>}` instead of `\fbox{<content>}`. It places the content first in a horizontal box of the given width before drawing the frame around it. The text width is given either by `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` (the latter is effected by list-like environment including quotations). If you want the frame to be exactly the text width than you need to subtract the frame rule width and separation twice (once for each side) from that value.

I'm not sure why you are using double `minipages` so I didn't changed anything here. Note that I additionally added a `%` after the trailing `{` to avoid a spurious space there and the change to `\caption`.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \framebox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      left part
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
      right part
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}}
  \caption{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
```

Note that `\framebox` reads the content as a macro argument and therefore you can't use verbatim or either catcode changing material inside it. If you want that you need to either use `\Framebox` from the [`realboxes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/realboxes) package or `\adjustbox{minipage=\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,fbox}` (also available as `adjustbox` environment) from the `adjustbox` package (both actually written by me). Depending on the content you could also use the `adjustbox` keys `width=\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,fbox` instead which *zoom* the content to the given width first. However, you seem to have text content where this is not recommendable.

Answer (score 1):

To make them equal to **paper width** as you requested, you need to firstly compensate for the `\fboxsep` and `fboxrule` widths and also adjust your geometry and remove the geometry parameters. If you want them to be equal to the `\textwidth` then replace `paper width` with `\textwidth` in the minimal below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true,left=0pt,right=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\fboxsep=5pt
\fboxrule=10.0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \color{red}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\the\dimexpr(0.5\paperwidth-\the\fboxrule-\the\fboxsep)\relax}
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\linewidth}
      \color{black}
      left part
      \end{minipage}}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{3pt}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\the\dimexpr(0.5\paperwidth-\the\fboxrule-\the\fboxsep)\relax}
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\linewidth}
       \color{black}
      right part
      \end{minipage}}
    \end{minipage}}%
  \captionof{figure}{An example program}\label{fig:An example program}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]